# How to delete sub tables child table entry when parent entry deleted in hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Cascade all let's to delete my subtable entries... But the sub tables sub table entry is not getting deleted. How can I solve the problem using cascade.

I am using hibernate hbm.

I tried using cascade='all'

Comment: What do you mean, "*But the sub tables sub table entry is not getting deleted.*"?

Comment: If A is a parent table of B and B in turn is a parent table of C and if you want to cascade delete C (through B), when A is deleted, then you need to set `cascade='all'` in B in addition to A. Where did you set it to *all*? You might be missing in B.